# AS2 Message Receiver

Tags: azure

I am introducing in the world of AS2 Servers and Messages.
I have created an Azure Logic App to receive HTTP Request with AS2 Messages and then use the action "Decode AS2 Message" to take care of the message.

I am having some problems handling in the decode the message received (sent through an local Console aplication developed by me).

[Azure Logic App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YASo.jpg)

**AS2 Message Body Received (after logic app run)**
{
  "content": "dGVzdA==",
  "aS2From": "test2",
  "aS2To": "test",
  "agreementName": "AgreementTest",
  "aS2MessageId": "",
  "receiverPartnerName": "TestReceiver",
  "senderPartnerName": "TestSender",
  "mdnExpected": "NotExpected",
  "mdnTypeExpected": "NotConfigured",
  "isNrrEnabled": false,
  "outboundHeaders": {
    "Message-ID": "",
    "AS2-To": "test",
    "AS2-Version": "1.2",
    "Content-Description": "body",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "binary",
    "EDIINT-Features": "multiple-attachments",
    "Mime-Version": "1.0",
    "AS2-From": "test2",
    "Content-Type": "application/edifact"
  }
}

**AS2 Message Headers (after logic app run)** 
  "AS2-From": "test2"
  "AS2-To": "test"
  "AS2-Version": "1.2"

Then, in the body of "Decode AS2 message" there is this error:
  "statusCode": "BadRequest",
  "errorMessage": "Invalid AS2 headers. One of 'AS2-To' or 'AS2-From' headers 
  are empty.",

Is there any problem in the message sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was adding the headers manually by using the parameters text in the logic app.
The solution was to put the headers tag coming from the HTTP Trigger in the Decode AS2 action. After that the logic app processed the AS2-From and AS2-To tags that were really coming in the HTTP Headers.